# Plain HTTP Request to UrlConnection (Java)

Tags: java, http-post, httprequest, urlconnection

### Make a request from request stream

I've an `OutputStream` contains the below `Request`. It's dynamic and everything(`Method`, `Type`, `Data`[Multipart/Non-Multipart/File]) can change. I just want **A Response Stream from that Request**.

```
POST /page.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla(Webkit) 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=myboundary 
 --myboundary

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a" 1 
--myboundary

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="b" 2 
 --myboundary--
```

### Building UrlConnection by hand is hard

I know I can make a `UrlConnection` by hand but that seems to be hard. To create it I need to add `headers`, `data-values` which I'll need to get by `RegEx` operation. I'm not getting how I would get multipart data by `RegEx`.

So, this approach is going to be hard also the request isn't always contains only `String` because sometimes **it sends `Files` too**. Also, I don't know much about `Http` format and I'm not confident.

So, *I'm looking for a library or method or easy way to make a `Request` from above `Stream` and get the `Response Stream`.*

Very simply : **Sending a Request with those values(OutputStream) and getting response in InputStream.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can send `Request` and get `Response` by using `Socket`.

We can create a new `Socket` and connect it with host and port. In the **OutputStream we can input the plain request**. We can get `Response` by `Socket.getInputStream()`.

---

*Request* : `Socket.getOutputStream()`
*Response* : `Socket.getInputStream()`

But, we'll have to connect to the `Server` with `Socket.connect()`.

```
Socket sock = new Socket();
sock.connect(host, port);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
dos.write(reqStr.getBytes());
dos.flush();
dos.close();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
//Here dis is the response.
```